# slideToggle() causes first li a to jump on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created very simple example, read many similar issues with slideToggle() but haven't been able to figure out the fix for it. 
How would I get rid of the jump on click of first li a when using slideToggle()? See it also in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/karin/heznn9rm/)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Click</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fourth</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
 ul {
        background:#ddd;
    }

ul li {
    display:inline;
    background:lightyellow;
}

ul li:not(:first-child) {
    display:none;
    display:inline;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('ul li:first-child').on('click', function () {
  $('ul li:not(:first-child)').slideToggle();
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to vertically align your `inline` li elements, in this case to the top:

```
ul li {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: top; // the important part
  background: lightyellow; 
}
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/heznn9rm/5/ .

Read more about `vertical-align` property: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

Another (and I dare to say more common) way would be to [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) your li elements to the left - in this case you probably also will want to use [CSS clearfix](http://themergency.com/css-clearfix-demystified/).

```
ul li {
  float: left;
  background: lightyellow;
}
```

+most basic clearfix on `ul` element containing floated `li`s:

```
ul:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/heznn9rm/6/ .

Answer (score 0):

When you click to an anchor (the `<a href='#'></a>` tag), the default browser action is to try to follow the reference (in your case it is `#`). This way, the browser will jump to the top of the page (if the reference is an id, the browser will jump to the element with this id).

To prevent this default behaviour using jQuery (your case) you can catch the event object and say to prevent the default behaviour. This way:

```js
$('ul li:first-child').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('ul li:not(:first-child)').slideToggle();
});
```

Notice that we now are grabbing the event object `function(e)` and saying to prevent the default behaviour `e.preventDefault()` for this event (e).